# Undefined method 'download'.intelephense(1013) with maatwebsite/excel in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I am using a piece of code to export to excel and everything works fine except the last line of code which is giving an undefined method error

Here is the code below:

```
function excel()
{
    $customer_data = DB::table('customer')->get()->toArray();
    $customer_array[] = array('id', 'detail', 'emailaddress');

    foreach($customer_data as $customer) {
        $customer_array[] = array(
            'id'  => $customer->id,
            'detail'   => $customer->detail,
            'emailaddress'    => $customer->emailaddress
        );
     }

    Excel::download('Customer Data', function($excel) use ($customer_array){
        $excel->setTitle('Customer Data');
        $excel->sheet('Customer Data', function($sheet) use ($customer_array){
            $sheet->fromArray($customer_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });
     })->download('xlsx');   //This is the line that's giving the error message
}
```

I have tried to change the download to `store` and `load` but to no success

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/export.html) you are calling a wrong method chain.

Try use:

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {

})->download('xls');
```

Or in your case:

```
Excel::create('Customer Data', function($excel) use ($customer_array){
        $excel->setTitle('Customer Data');
        $excel->sheet('Customer Data', function($sheet) use ($customer_array){
            $sheet->fromArray($customer_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });
     })->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: I get a `Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()` error if i use create

Comment: are you importing everything? 
The library is loaded (composer install)?

Comment: Yes, `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;` has been imported and composer install has been run